round function is inconsistent in rounding 2 decimal places
The code below is taken from my program. This block formats these float64 columns to 2 decimal places but rows 24-26 really won't change.
Here's a minimal reproductive example (I hope this is acceptable)
import os 
import pandas as pan

nlf = pan.read_csv("New Lines.csv")
nlf = nlf.iloc[:, 2:]

total_rows = len(nlf)
rows_to_drop = list(range(total_rows - 12, total_rows))
nlf = nlf.drop(nlf.index[rows_to_drop])

nlf.iloc[:, 14] = nlf.iloc[:, 14].round(2) # costs column
nlf.iloc[:, 20] = nlf.iloc[:, 20].round(2) # TWC Stores column
nlf.iloc[:, 21] = nlf.iloc[:, 21].round(2).copy()  # RRP column
nlf.iloc[:, 22] = (nlf.iloc[:, 22] * 100).round(2)  # GP% column
nlf.iloc[:, 23] = nlf.iloc[:, 23].round(2) # Weight column
nlf.iloc[:, 24] = nlf.iloc[:, 24].round(2)  # Height column
nlf.iloc[:, 25] = nlf.iloc[:, 25].round(2) # Width column
nlf.iloc[:, 26] = nlf.iloc[:, 26].round(2)   #Depth column

nlf.to_csv("nlf_decimal places.csv", index=False)


Can you share an [mcve]?

I get File not found: "New Lines.csv".

Sorry do we add a file?

No, create an actual [mcve] that defines the example data in itself.

Sorry I thought I already provided one by making the code more complete.

You don't need to read data from a csv in this example - just initialize a small sample dataframe. You don't need 8 different rounding operations if 1 will demonstrate the problem. And you don't need to write a csv if simply printing the dataframe will do. As stands, you haven't given us data to work with. And you've included stuff that is not related to the rounding issue you have.

Decimal rounding of binary floats is inexact. You can read more at numpy.round. If we have some sample data that demonstrates your problem, we can better access whether this rounding caveat is the issue.

@tdelaney Good advice. Similar advice and more is given at How to make good reproducible pandas examples

This is meant as a comment more than as an answer since I have no idea what your actual data is and therefore can't say what problem you are having with rounding some of your columns. But I would suggest that even those columns that you believe you are successfully rounding by looking at their displayed values, which have first been converted to strings, probably are not precise representations of the actual dataframe values. Here is the issue:
Floating point numbers generally use a base other that 10 (e.g. 16). This means that in general any number with two decimal places cannot be precisely represented in base 16. For example, a decimal number such as .50310 can be rounded to two places as .5010 and represented as a two-place base 16 number as .816 (8/16 = .5). But a floating point value of .10310, which when rounded to two places should be .1010, has a base 16 representation of .199999...99916 and requires an infinite number of places to represent precisely. This value may display as .1, but internally it will have a different value. So if you are dealing with decimal values and you want an accurate representation you should be using internally decimal.Decimal values.
If you want to round a decimal quantity to two decimal places, then use the `decimal.Decimal.quantize' method:
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> d = Decimal('127.3671').quantize(Decimal('0.00'))
>>> d
Decimal('127.37')
>>> str(d)
'127.37'
>>>

Let's say you have the following 'test.csv' file:



A
B




'some str'
1.2367



Then to read the 'B` column as a decimal.Decimal type:
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> def to_decimal(value):
...     return Decimal(value)
...
>>> df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters={'B': to_decimal})
>>> df.loc[0, 'B']
Decimal('1.2367')
>>>

